# How to detect a new angular component is loaded in layout component?

Tags: angular

We have an angular project that uses "router-outlet" to render components into layout (component) ..
As you know, the layout's ngOnInit runs out only for the first time of load and when a new component loads into the layout, layout's ngOnInit doesn't run again ..
I'm looking for to know how to detect a new component is loaded in the layout ..
Is there a way to know ?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make use of `activate` event for the same . Whenever we load a component in router outlet a activate event is emitted .

**Layout Component**

```
  <div class="container">
    <router-outlet (activate)="onActivate($event)"></router-outlet>
  </div>
```

**Template**

```
  onActivate(componentRef){
    // fires every time a new component is loaded
  }
```

Comment: Very nice. Thanks a lot.